# scrolltop is not working when overflow-y: auto;

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I've to scroll the window to the top using jquery

```
 $(window).scrollTop(0);
```

But it is not working , after spending time I've noticed that on my main `div` there is an inline style

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

when I removed that style it works after that , is there any way to work the jquery scroll without removing that line.

Answer (score 0):

you should do it use ref.
exmple

[how to working go to scroll top with owerflow-y-auto ? (in Nextjs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74392554/how-to-working-go-to-scroll-top-with-owerflow-y-auto-in-nextjs)

I asked this problem in this way in React and I solved it myself, then I wrote the solution as an update. you can browse my solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).